# Text Box Immediately Affect Label - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

All,

I have a view that has a label and a text box (no button!).

How would I make the label display exactly what is displayed in the text box at all times?

i.e. I type in "hello!"; the label should immediately display the "h" "he" "hel" as I'm typing it in. Does that make sense? (hopefully)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[urTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

.h

```
-(void)textFieldDidChange;
```

.m file

```
-(void)textFieldDidChange{


        urLabel.text = urTextField.text;


}
```

OR

If u use IB to create label and textfield then

.h file

```
    -(IBAction)textFieldDidChange;
```

.m file

```
-(IBAction)textFieldDidChange{


    urLabel.text = urTextField.text;


}
```

follow below

before that u have to make sure u have connected label and textfield to ur ivar appropriately.

select ur textfield

[image]

from popup select textFieldDidChange then save by cmd+s

then run.

Comment: Seems to work well, but when I tried this it is always one character behind. i.e. in the text field: "hel" but in the label: "he". Any fix for that?

Comment: The fix only applies changes when clicking back into the text field. i.e. I enter "hel", click away, click back into the text field, and the label updates.

Comment: Where do I place [urTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

Comment: take care and bye.getting late to home.have a nice day

Comment: That works perfectly. I didn't understand what you were saying. Good stuff! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Logic is the same as @Vijay's answer but implement in this.,

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{


  NSString *tempString; // now set
  tempString = textField.text;

  // This might just set your tempSting to the current character you type //

  // Just concatenate this to your label (which should be a property of that class)

  return 1;

 }
```

**Edit:**

Another easy/indirect way to go about this:

Instead of using a Label, use another textField in it's place. and set `textField.enabled = NO` so that it acts just like a label, and in the textField delegate methods you can just use

```
self.superTextField = textField
```

Comment: Same results as before, it updates one character too late. Copied from my previous comment -- when I tried this it is always one character behind. i.e. in the text field: "hel" but in the label: "he". Any fix for that?